# How to apply a function to all pairs of a vector

Tags: r

Good afternoon ,

My question maybe simple but i fails to solve this situation :

I have a matrix of `one column`.

```
dput(m)

m=structure(list(V8 = c(10L, 10L, 15L, 10L, 15L, 5L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 15L, 10L, 15L, 10L, 15L, 10L, 15L, 10L, 15L, 10L, 15L, 10L, 
15L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 15L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 7L, 10L, 10L, 15L, 15L, 10L, 10L, 10L, NA, 10L, 
NA, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 15L, 15L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, NA, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 15L, 10L, 10L, 5L, 10L, 10L, 15L, 
15L, 10L, 15L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -89L
))
```

And a function :

```
euclididan<-function(x,y){
  return(norm(na.omit(as.numeric(x-y)), type="2"))  
  }
```

I need to apply the `euclididan` to all `m rows pairs`.

I tried :

```
sapply(as.vector(m),function(x) sapply(as.vector(m),function(y) euclididan(x,y)))
```

I also tried :

```
VecFun <- Vectorize(euclididan )
outer(m,m, function(x,y) VecFun (x,y))
   V8
V8  0
```

The output should be a squared matrix of `89*89` with `zeros in diagonal`.

Thank you for help !

Comment: Your data is a frame, not a matrix. As such `as.vector(m)` still returns a `data.frame`, check `class(as.vector(m))`. Until you control your data types, your results will likely be not what you want or expect.

Comment: Using `outer(m[[1]], m[[1]], FUN = Vectorize(euclididan))` instead, I see errors of `svd(x, nu = 0L, nv = 0L) : a dimension is zero`, suggesting you either need to filter what you send to `norm` or somehow take better precautions with its results.

Comment: Yes this is exactly the pb , look my suggested solution

Answer (score 0):

While there will be more efficient ways to do this using vectorization, you can do it quite simply with a nested for loop:

```
output = matrix(nrow = nrow(m), ncol = nrow(m))

for (i in 1:nrow(m)){
  for (j in 1:nrow(m))
    output[i,j] = euclididan(m[i,1], m[j,1])
}
```

One note, this won't work with your function because there are NAs in your data. Using `na.omit` in your euclidian function means that when you hit one of those NA elements, you will be left with a zero length vector, which you can't calculate a distance for. You will need to do some other NA handling (set to some value, or just automatically return NA).

Comment: This is a primitif solution. The problem here is that m is dataframe and not a vector. The first thing is to unlist m then converting m to a vector. After that , we need to handle missing values.

Answer (score 0):

```
v=unlist(as.vector(m))

v=replace(v,is.na(v),0)

sapply(1:length(v), function(x) sapply(1:length(v),function(y) norm(na.omit(as.numeric(v[x]-v[y])), type="2")))
```

We could also :

```
VecFun=vectorize(euclidian(x,y))
outer(v,v,function(x,y) VecFun(x,y))
```